# Include NULL value in SubQuery Conparison

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query with sub query.

```
SELECT
        last_name,
        hire_date,
        salary,
        commission_pct
    FROM employees 
    WHERE
        salary IN
            (
                SELECT
                        salary
                    FROM employees
                    WHERE last_name='kochhar'
            )
        AND last_name <> 'Kochhar'
        AND commission_pct IN
            (
                SELECT
                        commission_pct
                    FROM employees
                    WHERE last_name='kochhar'
            );
```

Problem here is, my database contains entries which contains NULL in commission_pct. And commission _pct of kochhar is also null.

But in operator does not include it in result. What can be the solution to this ???

Comment: It will be great if you can load your table and data in sql fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Either use a substitute value which you never use such as -1:

```
  and coalesce(commission_pct,-1) in
  ( 
    select coalesce(commission_pct,-1) 
    from employees 
    where last_name='kochhar'
  );
```

Or use exists:

```
  and exists
  ( 
    select *
    from employees x
    where x.last_name='kochhar'
    and 
    (
      x.commission_pct = employees.commission_pct
      or
      (x.commission_pct is null and employees.commission_pct is null)
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists` and more complicated logic if you want two `NULL` values to be considered the same:

```
select last_name, hire_date, salary, commission_pct
from employees e
where salary in (select salary from employees where last_name='kochhar') and
      last_name <> 'Kochhar' and
      exists (select 1
              from employees e2
              where last_name = 'kochhar' and
                    (e2.commission_pct = e.commission_pct or
                     e2.commission_pct is null and e.commission_pct is null
                    )
              );
```

If you are doing comparisons on multiple fields, I would suggest using `join` rather than a bunch of conditions in the `where` clause:

```
select last_name, hire_date, salary, commission_pct
from employees e join
     employees k
     on k.last_name = 'kochhar' and e.last_name <> 'kochhar' and
        e.salary = k.salary and
        (e.commission_pct = k.commission_pct or
         e.commission_pct is null and k.commission_pct is null
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IFNULL function to handle the NULL values and assign a default value. Then, the values would be matched properly, as below:

```
SELECT
        last_name,
        hire_date,
        salary,
        commission_pct
    FROM employees 
    WHERE
        salary IN
            (
                SELECT
                        salary
                    FROM employees
                    WHERE last_name='kochhar'
            )
        AND last_name <> 'Kochhar'
        AND IFNULL(commission_pct, 0) IN
            (
                SELECT
                        IFNULL(commission_pct, 0)
                    FROM employees
                    WHERE last_name='kochhar'
            );
```

You may also consider re-writing the query for better performance, as other answerers have suggested.

Reference:

[Control Flow Functions on MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)